# substitute values in one text file into another text file

Tags: awk, syntax

I want to use awk to create a text file that includes a series of awk text lines with numbers that are replaced in. problem i am having is that the text will include awk syntax. ultimately, i want to end up with a line that looks like this:

```
($2 == "cs.cpool") && (h==1) {printf("%f        %s\n",$1==0.41369093,$2); a=1;}
```

so i want to have all of the above text, including the first bracket and the last bracket, print out along with the number 0.41369093 that will be supplied by another text file.

i have a text file for the numbers I want to feed in, i.e.:

```
0.41369093

0.00432739

0.03264715
```

I have tried to create this by including the following in a file called create.awk:

```
{printf("\n($2 == cs.cpool) && (h==1) {printf("%f   %s\n",$1==< %f >,$2); a=1;}") }
```

where the text file of numbers called input.txt replaces the `< %f >` in the above.

then executing with:

```
awk -f create.awk < input.txt > new.txt
```

however, i get the following error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1 source file create.awk
```

context is

```
{printf("\n($2 == cs.cpool) && (h==1) {printf("%f       >>>  %s\ <<< n",$1==< %f >,$2); a=1;}") }

awk: illegal statement at source line 2 source file create.awk

extra }

extra )
```

I would appreciate any assistance on this.
thank you,
Janet

Comment: So you want to have 3 different awk scripts with 3 different numbers for $1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Use  following escape characters `%%f`, `%%s` and `\"` instead of `%f`, `%s` and `"` inside the printf(). 
And you can use $1 outside double quotes to get the numerical values from the input file.

```
{printf("\n($2 == cs.cpool) && (h==1) {printf(\"%%f %%s\n\",$1=="$1",$2); a=1;}") }.
```

Comment: thank you, that worked! however, in a test where i have 3 of the text lines, and feed in a text file of 3 number - it assigns each of my 3 text lines the first number, then repeats the 3 text lines giving each the second number, then repeats the 3 text lines giving each the third number. any idea how to keep it from repeating?

Comment: how are you giving 3 text lines to awk?  you want each number to be assigned to respective text line?

Comment: here is my text file:

Comment: text file - test.awk:
printf("\n($2 == \"cs.cpool\") && (h==1) {printf(\"%%f %%s\\n\",$1=="$1",$2); a=1;}"); 
printf("\n($2 == \"cs.leafc\") && (h==1) {printf(\"%%f %%s\\n\",$1=="$1",$2); a=1;}"); 
printf("\n($2 == \"cs.dead_leafc\") && (h==1) {printf(\"%%f %%s\\n\",$1=="$1",$2); a=1; h=0;}"); 

file of numbers - input.txt:
-0.00432739
0.41369093
0.00000000

command: awk -f test.awk < input.txt > new.txt
I want first line to have first number, second line have second number, etc... but each line is assigned the first number, followed by each line assigned the second number, etc...

Comment: Instead of using 3 text lines for the three files - cs.cpool, cs.leafc and cs.dead_leafc, you can add an additional column of file names in your input text and use single print statement in yout test.awk file. something like this: `printf("\n($2 == \""$2"\") && (h==1) {printf(\"%%f %%s\\n\",$1=="$1",$2); a=1;}");` . In your input.txt file, add a new column of filenames next to the column of numbers.

Comment: thank you - that works much better! appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you approach this from a different angle. Instead of generating 3 different `awk` scripts, you can read items from the input file with numbers into array first. Then, read whatever file you need to process and substitute particular item from array.

For instance, here's a code where I give two files , numbers first and the processing file second. Where var[1], I read first item from array `var`, to get specific number. You can change that number at will, or even use a for loop to step through array and read  numbers from array automatically

```
awk '{i++;if (FILENAME == ARGV[1]) var[i]=$1  }{ if (FILENAME == ARGV[2]) print $2" " var[1]  }' input-nums.txt testfile.txt                                   
one 0.41369093
two 0.41369093
three 0.41369093
```

Comment: thank you, and it would be great to have fewer scripts and structure this more efficiently. i will try to construct it per your example, but this is a little more advanced than i understand - and i have yet to learn for loops!